# Add footnote Text to ggplot2 chart for individual hospitals

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to play around with how I plot my performance charts using bar plot and I am using hospital data which we collect. Now my intention is to plot performance of different variables but filter out those variables which performed well and just add them as a footnote text instead of plotting them in the bar chart. Here is how my data looks like:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  variables = c('temp','resp','oxy_sat','iv_fluid','iv_feed','adm_chart','temp','resp','oxy_sat','iv_fluid','iv_feed','adm_chart'), 
  hospital=c("Blossum hosp","Blossum hosp","Blossum hosp","Blossum hosp","Blossum hosp","Blossum hosp","mutte hosp","mutte hosp","mutte hosp","mutte hosp","mutte hosp","mutte hosp"), 
  category = c('vitals','vitals','fluids','fluids','feeds','feeds','vitals','vitals','fluids','fluids','feeds','feeds'), 
  value = c(95,60,89,100,67,96, 80,93,87,77,95,87)
)
```

This is how I separated variables with best performances of above 90% and created a footnote

```
best_vars <- dat %>% filter(value>=90)
list_vars<-as.vector(unlist(best_vars$Variables))

foot_note1 <- paste0("Variables that had excellent performance include : "," ",paste("'",as.character(list_vars),"'",collapse=", ",sep=""))
```

Now How can I plot a bar plot of those variables with perfomance below 90%  for each individual hospital then add footnotes for those hospital charts indicating those variables that had better performance for those same hospital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

best_vars <- dat %>% filter(value>=90) %>% mutate(lab_hospital = as.numeric(factor(hospital))) ## Add hospital to best_vars to differentiate later

for (i in 1:length(unique(dat$hospital))) { # create a footnote for each hospital
  list_vars <- as.vector(unlist(best_vars %>% subset(lab_hospital == i) %>% select(variables)))
  assign(paste0("foot_note", i), paste0("Variables that had excellent performance include : "," ",paste("'",as.character(list_vars),"'",collapse=", ",sep="")))
}

footnotes <- grep("foot_note",names(.GlobalEnv),value=TRUE)
footnotes <- do.call("list",mget(footnotes)) # put individual footnotes into single list

plot_vars <- dat %>% subset(variables %in% best_vars$variables)

ggplot(plot_vars, aes(x = variables, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  labs(caption = footnotes) + 
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust=c(0, 0.7))) + # edit the hjust if you want to have a different allignment for the labels 
  facet_grid(. ~ hospital)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you kindly separate the hospital charts to stand separately then have that footnote of best performing variables below the chart as you did for each hospital

Comment: Do you want the footnote to be different for each hospital? As in: Should Blossum contain a footnote mentioning iv_feed and resp, while mutte contains a footnote mentioning temp, iv_fluid, and adm_chart?

Comment: YES , I do want footnote to be different for each hospital

Comment: I edited my answer to satisfy your wishes. Let me know what you think